# qsort not sorting list of unsigned long ints

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

The following code is produced strange results when trying to sort of series of unsigned long ints. I have no idea why. It compiles warningless. The problem lies somewhere in my usage of qsort but I've scruntinzed that line for a few hours now. I think my comparison function is okay. I've tried semi-blindly trying all permutations I can think of to make sure I am passing the right arguments and still no dice. Any help locating my issue would be appreciated:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH 10

static int cmpfunc (const void *a, const void *b) {
    const unsigned long int x=*(const unsigned long int*)a, y=*(const unsigned long int*)b;
    printf("x=%lu ",x); printf("y=%lu ",y);
    if ( x==y ) {
        puts("returning 0..."); return 0;
    } else {
        if ( x>y ) {
            puts("returning 1..."); return 1;
        } else {
            puts("returning -1..."); return -1;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    /* declare the storage for our "array". Using malloc instead of [] because in
       real program array size shall be dynamic */
    unsigned long int *mystorage=malloc(LENGTH*sizeof(unsigned long int)); /* check for NULL */

    /* fill up array with values in non-monotonic order and show the values */
    for(unsigned long int counter=0;counter<LENGTH;counter++) {
        *(mystorage+counter*sizeof(unsigned long int))=(unsigned long int)(counter*(LENGTH-counter));
        printf("value is %lu\n",*(mystorage+counter*sizeof(unsigned long int)));
    }

    /* sort array */
    qsort(mystorage, LENGTH, sizeof(unsigned long int), cmpfunc);

    /* print out array again to see if it changed */
    for(unsigned long int counter=0;counter<LENGTH;counter++) {
        printf("value is %lu\n",*(mystorage+counter*sizeof(unsigned long int)));
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using that bizarre (and incorrect) pointer arithmetic, instead of simple array indexing?

Comment: use `sizeof *mystorage` to make your code more readable (and less fragile)  (in the places where `sizeof` is correct of course)

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth. Because I was forgetting how to use pointer arithmetic correctly. If you see the problem, please consider writing an answer like those below did rather than asking a pithy question. That way if you are the most correct among the response I have the option to choose your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*(mystorage+counter*sizeof(unsigned long int))
     =
         (unsigned long int)(counter*(LENGTH-counter));
```

... is incorrect. (I rearranged your whitespace a little.) It should be

```
mystorage[counter] =
         counter*(LENGTH-counter); // the cast is redundant
```

The following three are equivalent:

```
mystorage[counter]
counter[mystorage]       // yes, this weird thing is equivalent
*(mystorage+counter)
```

Compare the last line to your code. When you add a pointer and an integer, the compiler will already know to move by the correct number of bytes. Because you include the sizeof stuff, you have these two equivalent lines (that are different from the above three lines)

```
 *(mystorage + counter*sizeof(unsigned long int))
 mystorage[counter*sizeof(unsigned long int)]
```

It should be clear that these two will access outside the array bounds.

Comment: Agreed, @MattMcNabb, I've changed it

Comment: You are correct. It's been a while since I wrote in C and I had forgotten some basic C concepts which as pointer arithmetic incrementing by the sizes of the pointer type, not directly in bytes. Now I feel red-faced but thank you for your time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is wrong in the part

```
for(unsigned long int counter=0;counter<LENGTH;counter++) {
    *(mystorage+counter*sizeof(unsigned long int))=(unsigned long int)(counter*(LENGTH-counter));
    printf("value is %lu\n",*(mystorage+counter*sizeof(unsigned long int)));
}
```

When you add some integers to pointer compiler automatically use address arithmetic, so you should not use `*sizeof(unsigned long int)`. The same mistake in the printing loop. So use simple indexing `mystorage[counter]` or `*(mystorage+counter)`